# Trying to remove elements from an array in unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an old school styled light gun shooter in unity, I am trying to make it so when you defeat all enemies on screen, you move to the next section of the level. At first I used an enemy tag so when you destroy all gameobjects with that tag, you move onto the next section of the stage.

Unfortunately, I quickly ran into a problem that if every enemy on the stage has this tag, all the ones out of view must be destroyed too. I tried using an array, like if you destroy all enemies in the array, you processed to the next section, but even then, I keep getting errors if I try removing elements from the array. I'm assuming this is not possible and their must be another method to doing this. I wonder if anyone else ran into this same issue and has a soultion. Please, let me know! Please and thank you.

My code is listed bellow as reference:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FightZone : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Starter;
    public Transform nodeLocation;
    public GameObject[] EnemyPrefab;


    void Update()
    {
        if (EnemyPrefab.Length == 0)
        {
            Instantiate(Starter, nodeLocation.position, nodeLocation.rotation);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

for health:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int startingHealth = 3;
    public int currentHealth;
    public GameObject hurtFlash;
    bool damaged;
    public FightZone FZ;
    

    void Awake()
    {
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (damaged == true)
        {
            Instantiate(hurtFlash, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }

        damaged = false;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amount)
    {
        // Remove enemy from array

        currentHealth -= amount;
        damaged = true;
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);        
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use onbecamevisible and  onbecameinvisible?

Comment: I never heard of that? Could you provide an example?

Comment: It is well documented as part of monobehavior by unity

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0)? You can declare a `List<GameObject>`, which has a dynamic length and allows objects to be added to and removed from it.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I had looked into that but I'm still having the same issue, I just don't know how to make the game recognize that all the elements are gone not all the length being shorter if you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The examples I gave are for lists. Arrays are fixed size so there is no 'removing' items (You could copy every item to a new array of the new size but that is just pointless when you could use a List). If you want to keep using an array then your check to see if the level is completed should involve either looping through the array and seeing if every item is null, or giving each enemy in the array an isDead bool that you assign on death and then check for to see if all of them are dead.

I can't actually see any code that removes the item from the array? Destroying the gameObject will still keep the reference in the array, it will just become null.

To actually remove it, you should use something like:

`EnemyPrefab.Remove(GAMEOBJECT_TO_REMOVE);`

Or:

`EnemyPrefab.RemoveAt(INDEX_TO_REMOVE);`

If you're going to be dynamically adjusting the size, you would probably be better off with a list as nullFoo suggested.

Let me know if I missed the mark with this one as I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Furthermore, Unity MonoBehaviours implement a method called OnDestroy, which you could use that to automatically remove destroyed objects from the list